# Change color on active row based on active cell content

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Just getting started with google spreadsheets scripts.

I'm trying to change the background color of the active row based on the content in the active cell.

I'm not sure why this doesn't work, hope you can help :)

```
function setStatusColor() {

var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var ActiveRow = ActiveSheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
var ActiveCell = ActiveSheet.getActiveCell();

  if (ActiveCell == 'Plan') {
    ActiveRow.setBackgroundColor("#FFFFFF");
  } else if (ActiveCell == 'Offer') {
   ActiveRow.setBackgroundColor("#FFFF00"); 
  } else if (ActiveCell == 'Confirmed') {
   ActiveRow.setBackgroundColor("#00FF00"); 
  } else if (ActiveCell == 'Canceled') {
   ActiveRow.setBackgroundColor("#FF0000"); 
  } else {
    ActiveRow.setBackgroundColor("#FFFFFF");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    if (e) { 
        var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
        var r = e.source.getActiveRange(); 

        if (r.getRow() != 1 && ss.getName() == "Sheet1") {

        // Status in column 6 (F)
        status = ss.getRange(r.getRow(), 6).getValue();

        // Range to put background color to (rowStart, numberOfRows, columnStart, numberOfColumns)
        rowRange = ss.getRange(r.getRow(),1,1,6);


            if (status == 'Plan') {
                rowRange.setBackgroundColor("white");
            } else if (status == 'Offer') {
                rowRange.setBackgroundColor("yellow");
            } else if (status == 'Confirmed') {
                rowRange.setBackgroundColor("green");
            } else if (status == 'Canceled') {
                rowRange.setBackgroundColor("red");
            } else if (status == '') { 
                rowRange.setBackgroundColor("white");
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ActiveCell is a range actualy. Try with this:

```
var ActiveCell = ActiveSheet.getActiveCell().getValue();
```

Comment: Yeah because you set the background color on an integer, the return value of ActiveSheet.getActiveRange().getRow(); is an integer.

If you want to set the background color of the selection, set it on the range.
    ActiveSheet.getActiveRange().setBackgroundColor("#FFFFF");

You should take a look at the google api doc, realy great doc:
 https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range

Answer (score 0):

This ought to work:

```
function setStatusColor() {

var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var ActiveRow = ActiveSheet.getActiveRange();
var ActiveCell = ActiveSheet.getActiveCell().getValue();

  if (ActiveCell == 'Plan') {
    ActiveRow.setBackgroundColor("#FFFFFF");
  } else if (ActiveCell == 'Offer') {
   ActiveRow.setBackgroundColor("#FFFF00"); 
  } else if (ActiveCell == 'Confirmed') {
   ActiveRow.setBackgroundColor("#00FF00"); 
  } else if (ActiveCell == 'Canceled') {
   ActiveRow.setBackgroundColor("#FF0000"); 
  } else {
    ActiveRow.setBackgroundColor("#FFFFFF");
  }
}
```